# jQuery Google APIs fallback: Why does document.createElement() not work whereas document.write() works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, fallback

I want to user jQuery from Google CDN and I also want to implement a fallback strategy in case jQuery could not be loaded from Google. Of course, I know a good solution that always worked for me and still works:

```
<html>

<head>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- fallback: load local jq -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(jQuery); // something != undefined => works as expected
  </script>

</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Now I am wondering why this here does not work:

```
<html>

<head>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- fallback: load local jq -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){ 

      var script  = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src  = '/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js';        

      //this seems not to work :-(
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(jQuery); // undefined => but why????????
  </script>

</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

I know that the problem is that in case I use document.createElement('script') and then adding the just created script element to the  via DOM manipulation (without document.write() ) the new  element is indeed added to the DOM, but it is not loaded and executed at this very moment. Instead it is executed somewhen later. But I really expected that any script tag in the head is loaded and executed synchronously. It seems that this does not apply in the case I described above.

But on the other side the first example works just fine - so document.write() seems to do what I expected - but why?

Comment: never mind, I think I got it, see here: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/07/22/non-blocking-scripts/ .

When using DOM methods to add the new script tag to the head tag then we have a "Non-blocking script". That means it is loaded asynchronously!